# Why does CurrentUICulture.DisplayName say "English (United States)" and not "English (United Kingdom)"?

Tags: c#, localization

I'm in the UK, and I have a UK-bought version of Windows 7, with all settings I can possibly find set to UK (not US). When I run the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DisplayName);
Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DisplayName);
```

The output is:

```
English (United States)
English (United Kingdom)
```

I can't figure out why the first one says United States. I was going to include this in my about window (to help debug multi-lingual issues), but it's gotten me a bit confused!

Anyone know why it doesn't say UK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default [the CurrentUICulture property is driven by the Windows MUI setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441487wx%28VS.80%29.aspx).

MUI is the scheme whereby the language of the OS is displayed in a specific language and is separate from things like number and date formats. Brits don't get our own translation of the Windows UI...

Answer (score 4):

There is no British English translation of Windows (colour vs. color) - we get the US English version.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I should've realised with all the ZZZZZZZZs all over my Windows and apps :)